# Hide subreport on query result

Tags: reporting-services

I'm developing an SSRS report containing several sub-reports. The report gets a parameter and uses it to query an object ID which is used as parameter for all sub-reports. The problem ist that in some cases the query returns no object ID (dataset has no data records). In this case I have to hide the sub-reports and show a text message.

I don't know how to set the Show/Hide condition for the sub-reports. I could use a variable for that but I don't know how to set the variable value based on the query result.

Comment: `Hidden = IIF(RowNumber("MyDataSet") == 0, True, False)`? ([RowNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225(v=sql.90).aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jeroen writes, the Visibility value of the SubReport should be set as follows:

=IIF(RowNumber("MyDataSet") = 0, True, False)

Comment: Sorry to post in such a old thread, but I'm running into similar problems. But the SubReport nor the Body itself have a Hidden-Property, isnt it?

Answer (score 2):

On your subreport you can add a Textbox which has text the you'd want to show when no data is returned.
The visibility or the hidden property of the textbox should be set as

```
=iif(Count(Fields!SomeField.Value, "DataSet") > 0, true, false)
```

Similarly for the subreport put it in a Rectangle and set the visibility or the hidden property as

```
=iif(Count(Fields!SomeField.Value, "DataSet") > 0, false, true)
```